# Calendar Invite Shows Event Time in UTC

Tags: google-calendar-api

We're using the Google Calendar API to add events (appointments) to our staff person's calendar and also add a customer as an invitee.

We're experiencing a problem w/ the way Google sends out event invites, sending some of them out in UTC (for gmail and non-gmail addresses).

Below is the JSON of an actual example (personal information redacted):

```
{
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-10-29T13:00:00-04:00",
        "timeZone": "America/New_York"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-10-29T14:00:00-04:00",
        "timeZone": "America/New_York"
    },
    "attendees": [{
        "email": "[redacted]@gmail.com"
    }, {
        "email": "[redacted]@popsells.com"
    }],
    "creator": {
        "email": "[redacted]@popsells.com"
    },
    "description": "Location:[redacted]",
    "guestsCanInviteOthers": true,
    "guestsCanModify": false,
    "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": false,
    "id": "pop1026201[redacted]",
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "location": "[redacted]",
    "transparency": "opaque",
    "visibility": "default",
    "summary": "Photos & Video: 2014 Bayliner 16",
    "organizer": {
        "email": "[redacted]@popsells.com"
    },
    "reminders": {
        "overrides": [{
            "method": "email",
            "minutes": 120
        }],
        "useDefault": false
    }
}
```

Note the decision to specify the -0400 offset behind the time and also the second field to let Google know specifically which time zone we want this event expressed in.

In this example, the customer received this:

[image: Notice the time isn't specified as UTC until the very bottom of the email]

The actual raw .eml file straight out of our SMTP server (we receive a copy at our server in real-time of everything sent from Gmail) shows some interesting things (two screenshots):

[image: Notice the subject line very clearly says 5pm - 6pm and does not mention a time zone]

[image: Notice the UTC value here in the querystring - this value would be the intended time zone in examples where the invite is sent w/ the intended time zone]

This is a display issue only; the actual calendar event will be on the employee and customer calendars at the right time.  This display issue confuses our customers who:

a.) See this invite email before they see the event on their calendar, so they see what appears to be the wrong time referenced in the subject line (w/ no time zone specified).

b.) They're not military people or genius programmers (like us), so they assume times shown without a time zone would be in the local time of an event they're attending w/ a local business.

c.) Don't read the entire invite email to see the fineprint shows a different time zone than the one they might have expected.

d.) Most won't even know what the words "Coordinated Universal Time" mean after a time and may not even assume that's a time zone.

I have confirmed I am sending everything as suggested in the JSON.

I have confirmed the calendar of the organizer (specified in the JSON) is on America/New_York.  The JSON response from a hit to their calendar just now returned this:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"BKjXnZpXR6E5ueFWG3O[redacted]\"",
 "id": "[redacted]@popsells.com",
 "summary": "[redacted]@popsells.com",
 "timeZone": "America/New_York"
}
```

I'm sure the times when it sends with the correctly specified time zone aren't random but I have no information to decipher why Google sometimes sends ut correctly and other times does not.

I don't have access to the customer's calendar, but I have zero reasons to believe so many of our customers have their time zones set in UTC.  All of our customers are in the US.  It's not statistically reasonable to assume that 30+% of our customers have their time zones set to UTC.

Does anyone have any advice on what I can try next to get the subject line to identify either the time in the time zone specified which, in this specific example, would be 1pm - 2pm EDT (instead of just showing 5pm - 6pm)?

At wit's end w/ this problem.

Comment: we are experiencing this same problem, did you find a solution?